# Are vectors in c++ so slow?

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

I am making a program that solves this problem here: http://opc.iarcs.org.in/index.php/problems/BOOKLIST

and the only places i am using vectors are:

```
for(int i =0;i < total_books; i++){
    int temp;
    cin >> temp;
    books_order.push_back(temp);
}
```

and

```
for(int i = 0;i < total_entries; i++){
    int index;
    cin >> index;
    index--;
    cout << books_order[index] << endl;
    books_order.erase(books_order.begin()+index);
}
```

(here is my full code: http://cpaste.org/1377/)

The only functions i am using from vectors are vector::erase, vector::push_back and vector::begin.
For large inputs my code take more time than 3 seconds(which is the time limit for that problem), but when i remove the vector function, it runs much faster(but gives a wrong answer ofcourse)

I understood that it is wrong using vectors in this problem and that my algorithm is very slow, but i did not understand why it is slow.

If you know why the functions i am using are slow please explain them to me.
Thank you.

Comment: Any programming language can be abused... It's not the vector's fault.

Comment: std::vector is actually an array, and move to new array when requires more space. If your vector has to expand in very high speed, try use linklist instead.

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve? I'm reluctant to encourage any more of this code, but perhaps you would be interested in a different solution.

Comment: Amazing number of answers which think the problem is solved by using `reserve`. Folks, you're wrong.

Comment: This looks like a bad implementation of a queue. No need to invoke the ancient voodoo of the linked list here.

Comment: I don't see how your code solves that problem. There are no books in the problem, are you sure the link is right? To solve the problem you linked to, you probably want `std::make_heap`, `std::push_heap`, `std::pop_heap`.

Comment: wrt your problem, you probably want to use a priority queue or multiset in preference to a list or vector.

Comment: The link to the problem and the code are unrelated. That would be the first issue. I was going to point out that you need a different data structure that fits your problem better, but the fact is that first you need to understand what you need to solve :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The only functions i am using from vectors are vector::erase, vector::push_back and vector::begin

I would say this is your problem. [`vector::erase`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/erase/) is `O(n)`, the others are constant time and should not cause efficiency issues in online judge problems. Avoid the erase method.

However, in general, if you know the size of your array in advance, I would just use a simple array. Don't add any unnecessary overhead if you can help it.

To solve the problem you linked to though, consider using a [set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/): its erase method is `O(log n)`, as are its insertion methods. That is what you should use generally if you need random removals.

**Edit:** I forgot that C++ had [priority queues](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/priority_queue/) too, so look into those as well. Since you only care about the max here, it might be faster than a set, although they both have the same theoretical complexities (a heap can **retrieve** the min/max in `O(1)`, but removing it, which you must do for this problem, is `O(log n)`) in this case, and either one should work just fine.

Comment: thank you everyone for your answers, i will avoid using methods similar to vector::erase from now onwards.

Comment: @A.06: It's not a matter of avoiding a given method, it's a matter of knowing what is the complexity of the methods tied to a container so that you can pick the right container for the right task.

Comment: I would suggest `std::list` over either `std::vector` or `std::set` for this problem. The cost of inserting into a ordered list is O(log n), because that's the cost of searching an ordered list. Insertion itself is O(1). That O(log n) cost is same as the cost of adding an element to a `std::set`. On the other hand, removing the first or last element (or any element for that matter) from a `std::list` is O(1).

Comment: @DavidHammen a list won't work. You need to have a data structure that keeps your elements sorted, so you can get the next maximum after you get rid of the current one. You cannot efficiently do that with a list.

Comment: @DavidHammen - inserting into an ordered list os O(n), not O(log n).

Answer (score 7):

IMO the culprit is [`vector::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) as it will shift all the elements after the one removed. So unless you're removing always the last element it can be quite slow.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have called `reserve` to size your vector to the number of elements you have, calls to `push_back` will reallocate memory every time the new size will exceed the vector capacity. Consider using `reserve` to allocate memory sufficient for your elements and you should see a performance speed up, particularly if the vector is large. Also take heed of the other answers regarding use of `erase`.

Answer (score 2):

Removing elements from the middle of a vector (with `vector::erase`) is slow. This is because all the higher elements of the vector must be moved down to fill the gap left by the element you've removed.

So this is not a case of vectors being slow, but you algorithm being slow because you've chosen an inappropriate data structure.

Answer (score 2):

your problem is the call to "erase". If you check the documentation [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/erase/), you'll note that:

> Because vectors keep an array format, erasing on positions other than the vector end also moves all the elements after the segment erased to their new positions, which may not be a method as efficient as erasing in other kinds of sequence containers (deque, list).

either run the loop from the end or erase after the loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the vector has a certain number of elements in it in advance you can reserve enough space to contain everything to save yourself reallocations of space within the vector:

```
books_order.reserve(total_books)
for(int i=0 ;i < total_books; ++i){
    int temp;
    cin >> temp;
    books_order.push_back(temp);
}
```

However that's not the issue here, I'm sure if you profiled your code you would see a large overhead from the `.erase()` usage. Removing elements from the middle of a vector is slow because of how a vector is implemented it will need to move all the elements part the one that is removed. Consider using a different data structure instead such as `std::array` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need a vector to achieve what you are doing?

You have to keep in mind how vectors work: They're essentially dynamic arrays that resize as you add more items in them. Resizing a vector is an O(n) operation (where n is the number of items in your vector) as it allocates new memory and copies the items over to the new vector.

You can read about what vectors are good at [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/).

I would recommend using a standard array instead -- which seems completely plausible since you already know how many total elements there are (which is `total_books`)

Comment: You're making it sound worse than it is. Most times replacing an array with a vector will not cause any efficiency problems on online judges, because insertions to a vector are still amortized `O(1)` time. The problem here is that the array AND vector data structures are not suitable for this problem.

Comment: I need vectors because of the vector erase function, it is exactly what i need to solve the problem

Comment: @A.06 - no, it's not. See my answer, use a set.